# ¿ como saber el contenido de una carpeta de mi proyecto web en nextjs?

Tags: javascript, nextjs

amigos, estoy intentando obtener el contenido de una carpeta en mi proyecto nextjs.
La carpeta es:

> ../public/img/banner/

quiero obtener el nombre de todas la imagenes que hay dentro de esa carpeta para añadir de forma dinamica la ruta de las imagenes y no tener que especificar, una a una todas las imagenes.

Hay alguna forma de hacer esto?

Comment: y que has intentado? por experiencia te puedo decir que darle permisos a tu sitio de leer los contenidos de las carpetas de tu sistema en tiempo de ejecución es como dejar la puerta de tu casa abierta con un cartel que dice que no estas en casa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para ello, es necesario instalar dentro del proyecto el modulo fs y path con:

```
npm install fs path
```

Puede que aprezca algun error de que no se encuentra el modulo fs, lo solucionamos añadiendo al package.json esto:

```
"browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "path": false,
    "os": false
  }
```

luego importamos los modulos dentro de un archivo js:

```
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";
```

y creamos una funcion para obtener el nombre de los archivos en una ruta especificada:

```
const root = process.cwd();
export const getFiles = () => fs.readdirSync(path.join(root, "public/img/banner"));
```

esta funcion devuelve un array de los nombre de los archivos que contengan esa carpeta.

Para llamar esta funcion es necesario crear una funcion de nextjs, en Pages/index.js para recuperar datos estaticos es la siquiente:

1. en la parte superior de index.js importa la funcion por ejemplo:

> `import { getFiles } from "../service/itemService"`

2. al final de index.js, despues del cierre de la funcion home creamos la funcion para recuperar datos estaticos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

nota: tuve que colocar pantallazo porque no me reconocia la funcion para insertarla como codigo.

En files, se encuentran todos los nombres. Ahora lo insertamos como props en la funcion home de index.js asi:

```
export default function Home({ files }) {
```

ya con esto tenemos los nombres, en mi caso de todas las imagenes dentro de la capeta banner de mi proyecto. Yo estoy usando un componente de primereact llamado galeria para usarlo como banner y que las imagenes aparecieran como un carrusel. Pues a ese comoponente le paso los archivos asi:

```
 <Carousel files={files}/>
```

y ahora dentro del componente creo dinamicamente un json que usara el componente para leer las imagenes de esta forma;

```
useEffect(() => {
    let arr = [];
    files.forEach((file) => {
      let index = files.indexOf(file);
      // creando json
      arr.push({
        itemImageSrc: "/img/banner/" + file,
        thumbnailImageSrc: "/img/banner/" + file,
        alt: "Description for Image " + [index],
        title: "Title " + [index],
      });
    });
    console.log("array", arr);
    setImages(arr);
    bindDocumentListeners();

    return () => unbindDocumentListeners();
  }, []);
```

como pueden ver recorro el arrays de los archivos con un foreach y creo el json dinamicamente.

Quiere decir que si cambio las imagenes en la carpeta banner automaticamente me las leera y me las colocara en el carrusel!!!